# TCL: get single variable to be interpreted as multiple arguments

Tags: tcl

How can I get a single string variable with spaces in it in TCL to be interpreted as multiple arguments? I can't change the proc definition.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
set my_options ""
if { "$some_condition" == 1 } {
    append my_options " -optionA"
}
if { "$some_other_condition" == 1 } {
    append my_options " -optionB"
}
set my_options [string trim $my_options]
not_my_proc ${my_options} ;# my_options gets interpreted as a single arg here and causes a problem:
# Flag '-optionA -optionB' is not supported by this command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you use the [argument expansion](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) syntax:

```
not_my_proc {*}$my_options
# ..........^^^
```

Although I'd recommend using a list instead of a string:

- if for some reason the my_options string is not a well-formed list, you'll see an error thrown
- if any of the options takes a space, a list is the proper data structure:

```
set my_options [list]
lappend my_options {-option1}
lappend my_options {-option2 "with a parameter"}
not_my_proc {*}$my_options
```

Comment: Ohh fabulous - I knew there had to be a way! Thanks Glenn!